# c++11 Signal system

Tags: c++, events, c++11, lambda, signals

I try to use a "simple" signal system with C++ 11. I use the following class :
http://geekswithblogs.net/raccoon_tim/archive/2011/09/28/lambdas-and-events-in-c.aspx

but I have a problems (I use Visual Studio 2012):

***Problem description***

I cannot create an event like this :

```
RREvent1Arg<void> testEvent;
```

The "void" is not an argument type !!

I have try with "template specialization" something like :

```
template<typename T1, typename T2> class Signaler {};
template<> class Signaler<T1> {};
template<> class Signaler<void> {};
```

But I got some compilation problems:

> error C2065: 'T1' : undeclared identifier

Thanks for your help

Comment: Show us some code that we can try to compile.

Comment: Unless you've commited to this "simple" signals system, I would recommend you use a more ubiquitous (tried and tested) library such as boost signals2.

Comment: I have fixed the problem 2, it was a "full recompilation" problem ! Thx for your comments...

Comment: [Here is a signals system](http://ideone.com/r2Cn9z) that I just wrote. I'm bored.

Comment: Thanks a lot, the problem is that VS2012 does not support variadic templates :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answer 1:**

This `RREvent1Arg` from your article is not a general purpose signal/slot system.  It isn't written in a generalized way.  It's not surprising it hasn't been written to accommodate `void`, just as it isn't surprising that it doesn't handle a number of arguments besides 1 (given the name).

Note that it defines the callback handler as `typedef std::function<void (T1)> Func;` and then later tries to define things like `void Call( T1 arg )`.  You can't declare a function in source like `void foo( void arg )` in C++, and templates aren't allowed to create those either.  There would be ways of using overloading to fix this, but there are also ways of taking variable arguments, etc.

**Answer 2:**

Offhand I'm not exactly sure what the rules are for using the capture features of lambda on "this" are, especially if it's getting wrapped up as a `std::function`.  And because it's confusing I'd suggest saving this into another local variable, and capturing that by value:

```
static RREvent1Arg<int> testEvent;
class MyClass
{
 int a;
 void MyMethod()
 {
   MyClass *mc = this;
   testEvent += [=mc](int) { mc->SignalReceived(); };
 }

 void SignalReceived()
 {
   this->a = 10;
 }
};
```

But that's just me.  Maybe the `this` capture is good style.  Seems to cause problems for people in other questions.

Comment: FYI, you can capture `this` in an lambda, but it can only be captured by value, not by reference.  The big risk is that you have to guarantee that the pointer remains valid at least as long as the lambda still exists.

Comment: Thanks HostileFork, I agree with you and my goal is to improve it a little bit. First step is to handle "void" and later handler several arguments... but for both have no idea how ?

Comment: @Spectral If you really want to get into writing a signal and slot library, there's going to be a lot of ways to attack it.  If you want to go down the road of `RREvent<>` and `RREvent<int>` and `RREvent<int, int>` you can look into [variadic templates](http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/EhvU7k9E/).  You might also define a function type and then design your signal slot mechanism to  be parameterized with that.  Probably best to study and use what other people have designed first, though...

Comment: Yes, but Variadic templates are not supported in Visual Studio 2012 :-(

Comment: @Spectral Then don't use that.  :-)  [Qt Creator 3.0](http://qt-project.org/downloads#qt-creator)

Comment: Do you think that I can use "template specialization" for multiples arguments support. I have put an example in the question.

Comment: @Spectral You should make a new question instead of making an edit which makes existing answers not seem to make sense.  Ask this as a new question, and then [roll back the question in the history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/20544135/revisions) to version 4.  *(There is a "rollback" button)*.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this "simple signal library" that I use for a bunch of projects:

http://bitbucket.org/danielko/simplesignal

It doesn't handle accumulation of returned values because I don't consider that use case to be common enough to warrant the extra complexity.

What it does implement though is the signal/slot semantics; when you connect, you get a slot back that you need to keep alive for as long as you want to receive notifications from the signal. Destroying the slot (or calling `disconnect()` on it) will stop the signal from being delivered to the owner of the slot.

Hopefully it's simple and readable enough to be understandable; variadic templates take care of any number of arguments, no need for specialization.

Comment: Thanks a lot Daniel,

The problem is that it does not compile with Visual Studio 2012. There is no support of variadic templates !